# Integrating webpack into my WordPress workflow - Separate but related questions

Tags: javascript, webpack

This may be a bit of a long-winded one, but I am looking to use webpack going forward and can definitely see some advantages. However, some of the concepts are a little different to what I have been used to coming from a PHP-based environment and using Gulp.

There are a few things I am trying to get my head around so to help those interested with the post, I have highlighted my questions or what I am looking to achieve.

#### Background

I am building a boilerplate theme that has the usual WP files.

```
style.css
functions.php
sass
js
...
```

Amongst those files I have a directory called `gutenberg`. In this directory, I have a number of custom blocks (made using the @create-block package and ES5 syntax) that I am looking to package up similar to a React component. Each custom block folder contains:

```
{blockName}.php
index.js
style.scss 
editor.scss
utils-{blockName}.module.js
```

**What I am looking to do is generate a bundle.js file, but create separate files for each block so they can be imported on-demand in an attempt to reduce the initial bundle size. Ideally, this would be separate JS functions and CSS files.**

#### What I have achieved so far

Working through the Webpack documentation I have managed to get a basic implementation going, but everything seems to compile into one and I am looking for a bit more control/chunking, and obviously my current output does not take advantage of Webpack. I can then import the required scripts (hopefully using an Intersection Observer) when a block starts to come into view. However, I'm not even sure this is possible. This is just my mind thinking what might be possible.

My deps are:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@splidejs/splide": "^4.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.6.0",
    "sass": "^1.52.2",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.2"
  },
```

My webpack config currently looks like this:

```js
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const entryPoints = {
  app: "/js/app.js",
  style: "/sass/main.scss",
  editorStyle: "/sass/editor-styles.scss",
};

module.exports = {
  entry: entryPoints,
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "[name].js",
    clean: true,
  },
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?[c]ss$/i,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

and creates a `dist` similar or identical to this:

```
app.css
app.js
editorStyle.css
editorStyle.js
style.css
style.js
```

Now, the files that I am actually loading in are `app.js`, for my bundle. `editorStyle.css` for the styles in the editor, and `style.css` for the front-end styles. **So am I right in saying I don't need `app.css`, `editorStyle.js`, and `style.js`? If so, how can I removed these from the build?**

#### An attempt at code splitting

I did have a go at code splitting and got a result, but wasn't sure how I then use that chunk. I'm very new to ESM and have come from the standard `one-long-js-file.js` way of doing things

I have two blocks that use the same library, SplideJS. In those blocks `utils-{blockName}.module.js` I import Splide using the following method:

```js
import Splide from '@splidejs/splide';
import '@splidejs/splide/css/core';

...exported functions...
```

In my webpack config I included the following:

```js
   optimization: {
     splitChunks: {
       chunks: 'all',
     },
   },
```

Which created a chunk file along the lines of `vendor_splide-....-...-...{hash}.js`. **When I have a chunk like this, can I conditionally import it? The naming convention is obviously a standard method, can I have any control over how these chunks are named?**

#### Bundling

One thing I did come across was the size of the bundle once Splide was imported. Jumping from 8kb to around 70kb in development, and over 80kb in production. Splide claims their package is around the 30-40kb size so I wondered was I importing it multiple times. I read that including source maps is expensive and removed `devtool: "inline-source-map"` from my config but it actually increased the bundle size, only slightly. **Is it common for there to be discrepancies in claimed dist sizes of packages, or am I importing the library incorrectly (based on my above import statements)?**

Any help with integrating or answering some of my early questions would be greatly appreciated.